# How to fix bash script parameters from looping parallel to looping sequencially

Tags: shell, scripting, automation

I have a bash script that ssh in to different machines in a loop, this script also reboots the machines if there is a reboot=y parameter passed (using jenkins).

Issue -
If reboot = y, it fails to loop the ssh command for each host one by one, then echo "rebooting host" then finally run sh app-services.sh $APP

My goal is - after reboot is done I want it to ping the hosts one by one and if ping returns success, ssh back into the machine and restart the services of the application hosted.

My current script -

```
#!/bin/bash

IP_S="${HOSTS_STAGE}"
IP_P="${HOSTS_PROD}"

APP="$APPLICATION"

export APP
export host

if [ "${ENVIRONMENT}" == 'stage' ]; then 
    IP="${IP_S}"

elif [ "${ENVIRONMENT}" == 'prod' ]; then 
    IP="${IP_P}" 
fi 

echo "${IP}" 

for host in ${IP}; do 
    echo "########################################" 
    echo "## Running yum update on ${host}" 
    echo "########################################" 

    if [ "${REBOOT}" == 'n' ]; then 
        ssh -i "${id_rsa}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no dvopsadmin@${host} "sudo yum update -y"
        echo "##  Skipping reboot for ${host}"

    else
        ssh -i "${id_rsa}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no dvopsadmin@${host[@]} "sudo reboot"
        echo "##  Rebooting ${host}"
        ping -w 30 -c 1 ${host}

    # This is the other script that restart app services

    sh app-services.sh $APP


    fi

done
```

Comment: Please specify what the quoted script fails to do.

Comment: If reboot = y, if fails to loop the ssh command for each host one by one, then echo "rebooting host" then run sh app-services.sh $APP

Comment: Please add that info to the question.

Comment: @Gene I did, thanks

Comment: Why do you expect `ssh "df -h"` to reboot the machine?

Comment: @Gene lol of course not, it's just a place holder for me to see output

Comment: Change `df -h` to `reboot` or `shutdown -r now`.

Comment: Fixed the place holder commands to real commands.